# Place 3 images in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a simple thing: put 3 images in one layout - One is on the left, second is in the middle, third is on the right.

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/linearV" 
        android:background="@drawable/gradientbg" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="50dip"       
         >
         <ImageView android:id="@+id/headerimage1"           
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="100dip" 
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
         <ImageView android:id="@+id/headerimage2"            
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="100dip" 
            android:src="@drawable/image2"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/headerimage3"             
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:src="@drawable/image3"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />             
    </LinearLayout>
```

I've tried to add the : "android:gravity" tag to each ImageView but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: what is happening with this xml code now??

Comment: you should set width to 0dp, or use relativelayout or put each imageview inside a framelayout etc. where the framelayout has 0dp width.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Intead of LinearLayout you should use Relative Layout,

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/linearV" 
        android:background="@drawable/gradientbg" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="50dip" >

         <ImageView android:id="@+id/headerimage1"           
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="100dip" 
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

         <ImageView android:id="@+id/headerimage2"            
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="100dip" 
            android:src="@drawable/image2"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/headerimage3"             
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:src="@drawable/image3"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />           

    </RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: @reson
Lol, you have improved format, after the answer was successfully accepted :)

Comment: @trgraglia
yea, that's cheating ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you stick with a linearlayout, use layout_weight for the images and [WeightSum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aweightSum) for the linearlayout.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use RelativeLayout. Check this link:
http://android-coding.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/example-of-relativelayout.html

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

```
<LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/linearV" 
    android:background="@drawable/gradientbg" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="50dip"       
     >
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/headerimage1"           
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="100dip" 
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/headerimage2"            
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="100dip" 
        android:src="@drawable/image2"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/headerimage3"             
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:src="@drawable/image3"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        />             
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible by using a `LinearLayout`, just use the `layout_gravity` parameter, and then set its value to `center`, `left`, `right` .. or whatever else. You can even combine some of them.

You should take a look at the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_gravity).